# Sum of areas of trapezium given in the figure below.

Tags: trigonometry, circles, area

If angle$B_1OA_1 = 60 degrees$ and the radius of the biggest circle is $r$. According to figure trapezium $A_1B_1D_1C_1$, $C_1D_1D_2C_2$,$C_2D_2D_3C_3$......... and so on are obtained then the Sum of areas of all the trapezium is?

[image]

[Figure is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNSJO.jpg)

I am had figured out the length of $B_1A_1, D_1C_1$ and the line perpendicular to $(B_1A_1)$ and passing through O.I want to know how areas of trapezium are added to infinity will It be to infinity?

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting a link. Moreover, please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tired, where you are stuck.

Comment: HINT: sum of all areas is the area of triangle $OA_1B_1$.

Comment: @sahiba arora Question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

The altitude of the trapezium $A_1B_1D_1C_1$ is equal to $2r$.

Let $O_1$ be a center of inscribed circle of the trapezium and let $O_1K$ be a radius of the circle,

where $K$ is a tangent point to $OA_1$.

Since $\measuredangle O_1OK=30^{\circ}$, we get $OO_1=2r$.

Let $OO_1\cap DC_1=\{M\}$.

Thus, $M$ is a tangent point between this circle and $D_1C_1$, which gives that $OM=OO_1-MO_1=2r-r=r$.

Thus, $D_1C_1=2MC_1=2r\tan30^{\circ}=\frac{2r}{\sqrt{3}}$ and

since the altitude to $A_1B_1$ of $\Delta OA_1B_1$ equal to $3r$,

we obtain
$$A_1B_1=2\cdot3r\tan30^{\circ}=\frac{6r}{\sqrt3}.$$
Thus,
$$S_{A_1B_1D_1C_1}=\frac{\left(\frac{2r}{\sqrt3}+\frac{6r}{\sqrt3}\right)\cdot3r}{2}=\frac{8r^2}{\sqrt3}.$$
Now, let $x$ be a radius of the inscribed circle of $D_1C_1C_2D_2$ and let $O_2$ be a center of the circle.

Thus, since $\measuredangle O_1OK=30^{\circ}$, we obtain:
$$r-x=\frac{1}{2}(r+x)$$
or $$x=\frac{r}{3}.$$
Id est, $$S_{D_1C_1C_2D_2}=\frac{1}{9}S_{A_1B_1D_1C_1}$$ and now we can calculate the needed sum:
$$\frac{\frac{8r^2}{\sqrt{3}}}{1-\frac{1}{9}}=3\sqrt3r^2.$$
Done!